# Kernel quits on closing notebook

Tags: notebooks, kernel

Mathematica quits (exits) when the single notebook I'm working on is closed. How to prevent this? Win7, v10 Mathematica

Comment: I take it you mean the application mathematica exits, including the front end. The kernel is only the part that does the computations.

Comment: Does this happen after copying or cutting a large amount of data from the notebook before closing? I'm asking because that's the situation where it happens to me on OS X with v. 10.

Answer (score 4):

V10 has the option to have the program quit after the last window closes. Initially, you are prompted for your choice of the appropriate action after the last window closes:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you check the checkbox at the bottom right the default action will be to quit and the dialog box won't be shown again. I presume you must have clicked it at some time. As pointed out by Simon Woods this can be undone using the Preferences control panel:

[image: Mathematica graphics]